# Adding DATE column for export as CSV of ImageCollection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How can I add a `DATE` column for export as CSV of this `ImageCollection`?

```
var precipitation = precipitation.map(function(image) {
    return image
        .reduceRegions({  // <---- reduceRegions on the Image object
      collection:Micros,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      scale: 5000,
    })
    .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// you shouldn't need `var` because the `precipitation` variable is already assigned 
precipitation = precipitation.map(function(image) {
    return image
        .reduceRegions({  // <---- reduceRegions on the Image object
      collection: Micros,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      scale: 5000,
    })
    .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start'])
    .set('DATE', image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd'));     // add a formatted date property to the feature
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!  helpfull! 
could you please check these? beacause I ran it, but the results it the same... 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/421916/revisions

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, only adding selectors:

```
// Export 

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: precipitation.flatten(),
  description: 'Lluvias',
  selectors:'precipitation'['system:index'],
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

here the GEE code [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/981a1de3f968b931292f95b1668f8f96)